ApexChart charts are not the same size?
I'm trying to create a statistics component in my project, and I've decided to use ApexCharts...Now, everything was going smoothly until I discovered that not all charts are the same size, for example, one chart is extremely large (compared to the one who is tiny (like you're watching it from the 100px x 100px screen size), the 2 of them are then "normal size", the next one is a bit smaller, etc you get the idea.
I've tried using the CSS to define the height x width aspect but that doesn't work, I've tried defining height and width in the chartOptions themselves and even thought they are all the same (for each graph its width: 400 height: 400) they are all different size. Here is my code:
Location is smallest - Project is the biggest 
setLocationTickets(){
    const locationTicketCounts = this.calculateTicketLocationCounts();
    const locationDataPoints = locationTicketCounts.map(tc => ({
      count: tc.count,
      type: tc.location
    }));

    this.locationChartOptions = {
      series: locationDataPoints.map(tc => tc.count),
      chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        width: 400,
        height: 400
        animations: {
          enabled: true
        }
      },
      labels: locationDataPoints.map(tc => tc.type),
      colors: ["#008ffb", "#00e396", "#feb019", "#ff4560", "#775dd0", "#546E7A", "#26A69A", "#D4E157"],
      responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 480,
        options: {
          chart: {
            width: 200
          },
          legend: {
            position: 'bottom'
          }
        }
      }]
    };
  }


setProjectTickets(){
    const projectTicketCounts = this.calculateTicketProjectCounts();
    const projectDataPoints = projectTicketCounts.map(tc => ({
      count: tc.count,
      type: tc.project
    }));

    this.projectChartOptions = {
      series: projectDataPoints.map(tc => tc.count),
      chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        animations: {
          enabled: true
        }
      },
      labels: projectDataPoints.map(tc => tc.type),
      colors: ["#008ffb", "#00e396", "#feb019", "#ff4560", "#775dd0", "#546E7A", "#26A69A", "#D4E157"],
      responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 480,
        options: {
          chart: {
            width: 200
          },
          legend: {
            position: 'bottom'
          }
        }
      }]
    };
  }

picture of a project chart
picture of a location chart
